# Output in a table format in Java's System.out

Tags: java, string-formatting, tabular

I'm getting results from a database and want to output the data as a table in Java's standard output

I've tried using \t but the first column I want is very variable in length.

Is there a way to display this in a nice table like output?

Comment: https://github.com/assylias/Java-Text-Table-Formatter

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Use [`System.out.format`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) . You can set lengths of fields like this:

```
System.out.format("%32s%10d%16s", string1, int1, string2);
```

This pads `string1`, `int1`, and `string2` to 32, 10, and 16 characters, respectively.

See the Javadocs for [`java.util.Formatter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for more information on the syntax (`System.out.format` uses a `Formatter` internally).

Comment: Thanks just what I needed! I'll just add I needed to put \n at the end to produce a new line each time, in case anyone else finds that problem.

Comment: Or, better, a `%n` -- it gets automatically translated into the system's default line terminator.

Comment: How could I make left alignment in string table?

Comment: Left align: System.out.format("%-2s%10d%-16s", string1, int1, string2);

Comment: If I want to center align it, how to do it?

Answer (score 43):

Using [j-text-utils](https://code.google.com/p/j-text-utils/) you may print to console a table like:
[image]

And it as simple as:

```
TextTable tt = new TextTable(columnNames, data);                                                         
tt.printTable();
```

The API also allows sorting and row numbering ...

Comment: This is sort of a pain to use, but it is nicer than continually adjusting string formatting. It'd be even better if:
- the source jar was published to the Maven repo
- it was in a well known repo like Central

Comment: It is too late for Greg Chabala. I am confident you have discovered a solution, but for others. Maven repo: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.massisframework/j-text-utils/0.3.4

Answer (score 22):

I may be very late for the Answer but here a simple and generic solution

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

public class TableGenerator {

    private int PADDING_SIZE = 2;
    private String NEW_LINE = "\n";
    private String TABLE_JOINT_SYMBOL = "+";
    private String TABLE_V_SPLIT_SYMBOL = "|";
    private String TABLE_H_SPLIT_SYMBOL = "-";

    public String generateTable(List<String> headersList, List<List<String>> rowsList,int... overRiddenHeaderHeight)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        int rowHeight = overRiddenHeaderHeight.length > 0 ? overRiddenHeaderHeight[0] : 1; 

        Map<Integer,Integer> columnMaxWidthMapping = getMaximumWidhtofTable(headersList, rowsList);

        stringBuilder.append(NEW_LINE);
        stringBuilder.append(NEW_LINE);
        createRowLine(stringBuilder, headersList.size(), columnMaxWidthMapping);
        stringBuilder.append(NEW_LINE);


        for (int headerIndex = 0; headerIndex < headersList.size(); headerIndex++) {
            fillCell(stringBuilder, headersList.get(headerIndex), headerIndex, columnMaxWidthMapping);
        }

        stringBuilder.append(NEW_LINE);

        createRowLine(stringBuilder, headersList.size(), columnMaxWidthMapping);


        for (List<String> row : rowsList) {

            for (int i = 0; i < rowHeight; i++) {
                stringBuilder.append(NEW_LINE);
            }

            for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row.size(); cellIndex++) {
                fillCell(stringBuilder, row.get(cellIndex), cellIndex, columnMaxWidthMapping);
            }

        }

        stringBuilder.append(NEW_LINE);
        createRowLine(stringBuilder, headersList.size(), columnMaxWidthMapping);
        stringBuilder.append(NEW_LINE);
        stringBuilder.append(NEW_LINE);

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private void fillSpace(StringBuilder stringBuilder, int length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            stringBuilder.append(" ");
        }
    }

    private void createRowLine(StringBuilder stringBuilder,int headersListSize, Map<Integer,Integer> columnMaxWidthMapping)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < headersListSize; i++) {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(TABLE_JOINT_SYMBOL);   
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < columnMaxWidthMapping.get(i) + PADDING_SIZE * 2 ; j++) {
                stringBuilder.append(TABLE_H_SPLIT_SYMBOL);
            }
            stringBuilder.append(TABLE_JOINT_SYMBOL);
        }
    }


    private Map<Integer,Integer> getMaximumWidhtofTable(List<String> headersList, List<List<String>> rowsList)
    {
        Map<Integer,Integer> columnMaxWidthMapping = new HashMap<>();

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < headersList.size(); columnIndex++) {
            columnMaxWidthMapping.put(columnIndex, 0);
        }

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < headersList.size(); columnIndex++) {

            if(headersList.get(columnIndex).length() > columnMaxWidthMapping.get(columnIndex))
            {
                columnMaxWidthMapping.put(columnIndex, headersList.get(columnIndex).length());
            }
        }


        for (List<String> row : rowsList) {

            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < row.size(); columnIndex++) {

                if(row.get(columnIndex).length() > columnMaxWidthMapping.get(columnIndex))
                {
                    columnMaxWidthMapping.put(columnIndex, row.get(columnIndex).length());
                }
            }
        }

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < headersList.size(); columnIndex++) {

            if(columnMaxWidthMapping.get(columnIndex) % 2 != 0)
            {
                columnMaxWidthMapping.put(columnIndex, columnMaxWidthMapping.get(columnIndex) + 1);
            }
        }


        return columnMaxWidthMapping;
    }

    private int getOptimumCellPadding(int cellIndex,int datalength,Map<Integer,Integer> columnMaxWidthMapping,int cellPaddingSize)
    {
        if(datalength % 2 != 0)
        {
            datalength++;
        }

        if(datalength < columnMaxWidthMapping.get(cellIndex))
        {
            cellPaddingSize = cellPaddingSize + (columnMaxWidthMapping.get(cellIndex) - datalength) / 2;
        }

        return cellPaddingSize;
    }

    private void fillCell(StringBuilder stringBuilder,String cell,int cellIndex,Map<Integer,Integer> columnMaxWidthMapping)
    {

        int cellPaddingSize = getOptimumCellPadding(cellIndex, cell.length(), columnMaxWidthMapping, PADDING_SIZE);

        if(cellIndex == 0)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(TABLE_V_SPLIT_SYMBOL); 
        }

        fillSpace(stringBuilder, cellPaddingSize);
        stringBuilder.append(cell);
        if(cell.length() % 2 != 0)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(" ");
        }

        fillSpace(stringBuilder, cellPaddingSize);

        stringBuilder.append(TABLE_V_SPLIT_SYMBOL); 

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TableGenerator tableGenerator = new TableGenerator();

        List<String> headersList = new ArrayList<>(); 
        headersList.add("Id");
        headersList.add("F-Name");
        headersList.add("L-Name");
        headersList.add("Email");

        List<List<String>> rowsList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            List<String> row = new ArrayList<>(); 
            row.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            row.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            row.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            row.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

            rowsList.add(row);
        }

        System.out.println(tableGenerator.generateTable(headersList, rowsList));
    }
}
```

With this kind of Output

```
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|                   Id                   |                F-Name                  |                 L-Name                 |                  Email                 |
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|  70a56f25-d42a-499c-83ac-50188c45a0ac  |  aa04285e-c135-46e2-9f90-988bf7796cd0  |  ac495ba7-d3c7-463c-8c24-9ffde67324bc  |  f6b5851b-41e0-4a4e-a237-74f8e0bff9ab  |
|  6de181ca-919a-4425-a753-78d2de1038ef  |  c4ba5771-ccee-416e-aebd-ef94b07f4fa2  |  365980cb-e23a-4513-a895-77658f130135  |  69e01da1-078e-4934-afb0-5afd6ee166ac  |
|  f3285f33-5083-4881-a8b4-c8ae10372a6c  |  46df25ed-fa0f-42a4-9181-a0528bc593f6  |  d24016bf-a03f-424d-9a8f-9a7b7388fd85  |  4b976794-aac1-441e-8bd2-78f5ccbbd653  |
|  ab799acb-a582-45e7-ba2f-806948967e6c  |  d019438d-0a75-48bc-977b-9560de4e033e  |  8cb2ad11-978b-4a67-a87e-439d0a21ef99  |  2f2d9a39-9d95-4a5a-993f-ceedd5ff9953  |
|  78a68c0a-a824-42e8-b8a8-3bdd8a89e773  |  0f030c1b-2069-4c1a-bf7d-f23d1e291d2a  |  7f647cb4-a22e-46d2-8c96-0c09981773b1  |  0bc944ef-c1a7-4dd1-9eef-915712035a74  |
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The only imports you need are :
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

Comment: Wouldn't bad if you could have provided a public static void main with an actual example.

Comment: This solution cannot be called "simple"

Comment: Even 7 years after you posted this solution, it's saving us developers time and effort.  I needed just this solution for an ad hoc delta report.  Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

I've created a project that can build much advanced table views. If you supposed to **print** the table, the width of the table going to have a limit.
I have applied it in one of my own project to get a customer invoice print.  Following is an example of the print view.

```
           PLATINUM COMPUTERS(PVT) LTD          
     NO 20/B, Main Street, Kandy, Sri Lanka.    
  Land: 812254630 Mob: 712205220 Fax: 812254639 

                CUSTOMER INVOICE                

+-----------------------+----------------------+
|INFO                   |CUSTOMER              |
+-----------------------+----------------------+
|DATE: 2015-9-8         |ModernTec Distributors|
|TIME: 10:53:AM         |MOB: +94719530398     |
|BILL NO: 12            |ADDRES: No 25, Main St|
|INVOICE NO: 458-80-108 |reet, Kandy.          |
+-----------------------+----------------------+
|                SELLING DETAILS               |
+-----------------+---------+-----+------------+
|ITEM             | PRICE($)|  QTY|       VALUE|
+-----------------+---------+-----+------------+
|Optical mouse    |   120.00|   20|     2400.00|
|Gaming keyboard  |   550.00|   30|    16500.00|
|320GB SATA HDD   |   220.00|   32|     7040.00|
|500GB SATA HDD   |   274.00|   13|     3562.00|
|1TB SATA HDD     |   437.00|   11|     4807.00|
|RE-DVD ROM       |   144.00|   29|     4176.00|
|DDR3 4GB RAM     |   143.00|   13|     1859.00|
|Blu-ray DVD      |    94.00|   28|     2632.00|
|WR-DVD           |   122.00|   34|     4148.00|
|Adapter          |   543.00|   28|    15204.00|
+-----------------+---------+-----+------------+
|               RETURNING DETAILS              |
+-----------------+---------+-----+------------+
|ITEM             | PRICE($)|  QTY|       VALUE|
+-----------------+---------+-----+------------+
|320GB SATA HDD   |   220.00|    4|      880.00|
|WR-DVD           |   122.00|    7|      854.00|
|1TB SATA HDD     |   437.00|    7|     3059.00|
|RE-DVD ROM       |   144.00|    4|      576.00|
|Gaming keyboard  |   550.00|    6|     3300.00|
|DDR3 4GB RAM     |   143.00|    7|     1001.00|
+-----------------+---------+-----+------------+
                              GROSS   59,928.00 
                       DISCOUNT(5%)    2,996.40 
                             RETURN    9,670.00 
                            PAYABLE   47,261.60 
                               CASH   20,000.00 
                             CHEQUE   15,000.00 
                    CREDIT(BALANCE)   12,261.60 






  ---------------------   --------------------- 
     CASH COLLECTOR         GOODS RECEIVED BY   

             soulution by clough.com
```

[This](https://github.com/thedathoudarya/wagu/blob/wagu-branch/examples/set3/Bill.java) is the code for above print view and you can find the library (Wagu) in [here](https://github.com/thedathoudarya/wagu).

Comment: Mr. @CLOUGH , I really appreciated your answers. its a great way to generate invoice.. i am also working on project but I do not want RETURNING DETAIL section in my invoice... can you help me through this.. I am unable to cut this section

Comment: @Rafi Abro - Sure thing. You can refer to the examples I added [here](https://github.com/thedathoudarya/WAGU-data-in-table-view/tree/wagu-branch/examples)

Comment: yes I referred [link this](https://github.com/thedathoudarya/WAGU-data-in-table-view/blob/wagu-branch/examples/set3/Bill.java) post, I have written all the code the way you have defined in ur example, when I cut the section of "Returning Details" I get error, can you help me

Comment: @Rafi Abro - email me your code and a sample output you are expecting to get. My email thedath.oudarya@gmail.com

Comment: @CLOUGH, kindly have a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045336/modification-in-wagu-data-in-table-view-library) post sir

Comment: Does this works for non-console output? It seem that the alignment will go crazy if I attempt to print this to TextArea in javafx

Comment: @LZH - Yes, this works fine. But, you need to change the typeface of the TextArea to **Monospace**.

Comment: Does it published into maven central repository?

Comment: @Hubbitus, No it hasn't.

Comment: Do you plan do that?

Comment: @Hubbitus, Actually I'm planning to reprogram the logic of this library. After all that, I'll be publishing this on maven.

Answer (score 9):

Check this out. The author provides a simple but elegant solution which doesn't require any 3rd party library. http://www.ksmpartners.com/2013/08/nicely-formatted-tabular-output-in-java/

[image: An example of the TableBuilder and sample output]

Comment: This solution i very well using a 3rd party library: Apache Lang 
But still the best solution for my need. 1+

Comment: Copying stray code from the internet is actually slightly worse than a 3rd party library; it's a library that no one even bothered to package for others to reuse.

Comment: downvote because of posting an image of code rather than posting the code

Answer (score 9):

Because most of solutions is bit outdated I could also suggest [asciitable](https://github.com/vdmeer/asciitable) which already available in maven (`de.vandermeer:asciitable:0.3.2`) and may produce very complicated configurations.

## Features (by offsite):

- Text table with some flexibility for rules and content, alignment, format, padding, margins, and frames:
- add text, as often as required in many different formats (string, text provider, render provider, ST, clusters),
- removes all excessive white spaces (tabulators, extra blanks, combinations of carriage return and line feed),
- 6 different text alignments: left, right, centered, justified, justified last line left, justified last line right,
- flexible width, set for text and calculated in many different ways for rendering
- padding characters for left and right padding (configurable separately)
- padding characters for top and bottom padding (configurable separately)
- several options for drawing grids
- rules with different styles (as supported by the used grid theme: normal, light, strong, heavy)
- top/bottom/left/right margins outside a frame
- character conversion to generated text suitable for further process, e.g. for LaTeX and HTML

And usage still looks easy:

```
AsciiTable at = new AsciiTable();

at.addRule();
at.addRow("row 1 col 1", "row 1 col 2");
at.addRule();
at.addRow("row 2 col 1", "row 2 col 2");
at.addRule();

System.out.println(at.render()); // Finally, print the table to standard out.
```

Comment: Nice and well documented library

Answer (score 8):

```
public class Main {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
   String format = "|%1$-10s|%2$-10s|%3$-20s|\n";
   System.out.format(format, "A", "AA", "AAA");
   System.out.format(format, "B", "", "BBBBB");
   System.out.format(format, "C", "CCCCC", "CCCCCCCC");

   String ex[] = { "E", "EEEEEEEEEE", "E" };

   System.out.format(String.format(format, (Object[]) ex));
 }
}
```

differece in sizes of input doesnt effect the output

Answer (score 0):

Check out the class [java.util.Formatter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: System.out.format uses Formatter : see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html