# Formatting Java Output Like a Table

Tags: java, formatting

I am attempting to output information regarding students stored by my program in a tabular-like format as \t does not always provide the correct spacing. In order to do so, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745239/1692226) and have attempted to enable a similar solution. However, I am obtaining errors with the format lines in my code when I attempt to execute it as such.

```
public void displayStudents (){
    System.out.println ("\n-----------------------------");
    System.out.println ("Email System - Display Students");
    System.out.println ("-----------------------------");
    System.out.format("%10s%15d%15s%15s%20s", "Grade", "Last Name", "First Name", "Student Number", "Parent Email");

    StudentNode current = top;
    while (current != null){
        Student read = current.getStudentNode();
        System.out.format ("%10s%15d%15s%15s%20s", ""+read.getClass(), read.getLastName(), read.getFirstName(), ""+read.getStudentNum(), read.getParentEmail());
        //This will output with a set number of character spaces per field, giving the list a table-like quality
    }
}//End of displayStudents
```

The goal of the code is to output in a manner similar to the following image.
[image]

Please aid me in finding my error. Is there perhaps an alternatively method to perform this?

Thanks.

EDIT: The error(s) I am getting are

```
GradeException in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
at StudentList.displayStudents(StudentList.java:184)
at OnlineCommunications.emailOption(OnlineCommunications.java:403)
at OnlineCommunications.main(OnlineCommunications.java:451)
```

It should be noted that Grade is an integer and Long is a double.

Comment: What kind of problem do you have?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added the error. @LuiggiMendoza

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because`%d` is for numeric non-floating point values (`int`, `long`, etc).

In the line where you print the titles, you have to use `%XXs` (where XX is a number) since you're passing `String`s as parameters:

```
System.out.format("%10s%15s%15s%15s%20s",
    "Grade", "Last Name", "First Name", "Student Number", "Parent Email");
```

In the line inside the `while-loop`, you need to set `%d` for the `int` and `long` variables, like Grade and Student Number, there's no need to convert it to `String` using `"" + intProperty`:

```
System.out.format ("%10d%15s%15s%15d%20s",
    read.getClass(), read.getLastName(), read.getFirstName(),
    read.getStudentNum(), read.getParentEmail());
```

Since it looks like you want to format the output to the left (and not to the right), you should add a hypen (-) symbol before the XX number:

```
//similar for title
System.out.format ("%-10d%-15s%-15s%-15d%-20s",
    read.getClass(), read.getLastName(), read.getFirstName(),
    read.getStudentNum(), read.getParentEmail());
```

Note: I assumed `read.getClass()` and `read.getStudentNum()` would return the `Grade` and `Student number` values as `int` or `long`.

Comment: May I know what should you use is the data type is double>

Comment: @2dollar20cents `%f` is what you're looking for. You can read more from the javadoc of [`Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is:

> 10s **%15d** %15s%15s%20s

should be:

> 10s **%15s** %15s%15s%20s

This is because all of the input parameters are `String`, so `d` ([which applies to integral types only](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)) is invalid.

Comment: Just a small additional question, it seems that this right aligns the "cells" of the "table". Is there any way to make it left align instead?

Comment: @mCode that's covered in my answer.