# Receipt printer does not accept HTML formats

Tags: java, html, netbeans, printing, jeditorpane

Referring to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397585/set-different-font-formats-in-jtextarea), I have converted my invoice format into `JEditorPane` in `HTML` format. Invoice format is good. The problem is when I print it, my receipt printer does not accept the `HTML` format, like bold, italic, border styles etc. When I print into XML file, it gives me required output like picture is given below:

[image]

But when I give print command to receipt printer, it prints like:

[image]

Comment: You should contact Abrosoft

Comment: Does it work on other printers? Maybe the printer's not capable of printing the markup

Comment: Receipt Printer Model is: Thermal Receipt Printer, BC 85AC

Comment: Anyone know, what should I do?