# How to format a simple table in Java?

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to create a table that looks like this:
[image: Table to be created.]

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
public class YourName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Tecken \tGrundamne \tAtomnummer \tAtommassa \tMasstal");
        System.out.println("==================================================================");
        System.out.print("Ag \tSilver");
        int agNumber = 47;
        float agMass = 107.8682f;
        float agMasstal = Math.round (agMass - agNumber);
        System.out.print(agNumber);
        System.out.print(agMass);
        System.out.print(agMasstal);

        System.out.print("Au \tGuld");
        int auNumber = 79;
        float auMass = 196.96654f;
        float auMasstal = Math.round (auMass - auNumber);
        System.out.print(auNumber);
        System.out.print(auMass);
        System.out.print(auMasstal);

        System.out.print("C \tKol");
        int cNumber = 6;
        float cMass = 12.01f;
        float cMasstal = Math.round (cMass - cNumber);
        System.out.print(cNumber);
        System.out.print(cMass);
        System.out.print(cMasstal);
    }
}
```

3 questions:

1. How can I get each print on a new line? As you can tell from the image, I want to have the last line as C [tab] Kol [tab] 6 [tab] 12.01 [tab] 6, for instance.
2. How can I make tabs between each print?
3. When I compile and run, it seems that the `Math.round` includes a single decimal, and I would like it to be without, as in the attached image.

Please do not mind the Swedish headings and words.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok so I realized my own mistake and changed this:

`System.out.print(agMasstal);
System.out.print(auMasstal);
System.out.print(cMasstal);`

to 

`System.out.println(agMasstal);
System.out.println(auMasstal);
System.out.println(cMasstal);`

which solved question 1

Comment: Check out `String.format`, will lead to prettier code in this case..

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745206/output-in-a-table-format-in-javas-system-out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. either use `System.out.println("text"); which inserts a linebreak after the text, or insert the linebreak, where you want it with "\n".
2. insert "\t", e.g. `System.out.print(cNumber+"\t")`;
3. use `long` instead of `float` for the rounded values, since `float` is a floating point number.

Answer (score 1):

You can pretty up your code quite a bit using `String.format`.

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final String HEADER_LINE = "Tecken \tGrundamne \tAtomnummer \tAtommassa \tMasstal"
    private static final final String SEPARATOR = "==================================================================";
    final String LINE_TEMPLATE = "%s \t%s \t %d\t %f\t %d";

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(HEADER_LINE);
        System.out.println(SEPARATOR);
        System.out.println(String.format(LINE_TEMPLATE, "Ag", "Silver", agNumber, agMass, agMasstall));
        System.out.println(String.format(LINE_TEMPLATE, "Au", "Gold", auNumber, auMass, auMasstall));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. How can I get each print on a new line? As you can tell from the image, I want to have the last line as C [tab] Kol [tab] 6 [tab] 12.01 [tab] 6, for instance.

   **Answer:** Use `System.out.println(agNumber);`
2. How can I make tabs between each print?

   **Answer:** Use `System.out.println(agNumber+"\t")`
3. When I compile and run, it seems that the Math.round includes a single decimal, and I would like it to be without, as in the attached image.

   **Answer:** use long instead of float.