# Output total for 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

The program is to enter in scores for 4 players and as you are entering the scores it is supposed to show the current shows on the right like this image.
I cannot use System.out.format because I am not using data from a database

What it is supposed to look like:

[image]

I have what I think should be a logic for it, I just don't know how to output it so it looks the same as the picture.
Here is the code so far:

```
private static final int NUMBER_OF_ENDS = 10;
private static String[] player = new String[4];
private static int[][] scores = new int[4][NUMBER_OF_ENDS];
private static int totalsOne = 0;
private static int totalsTwo = 0;
private static int totalsThree = 0;
private static int totalsFour = 0;


public static void addPlayer() {
    //for loop to add player to player array
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int counter = 0; counter < player.length; counter++) {
        System.out.println("Enter player #" + counter + " name");
        player[counter] = input.nextLine();

    }
}

public static void addScores() {
    //for loops to add scores to particular end and show user current score
    String output = "";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int inner = 0; inner < NUMBER_OF_ENDS; inner++) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < player.length; counter++) {

            System.out.print("Enter score number " + (inner + 1) + " score for " + player[counter] + "---->");
            scores[counter][inner] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Current Scores-\n");
            System.out.println(getResults(inner));
            if (counter ==0){
                totalsOne += scores[counter][inner];

            }else if(counter ==1){
                totalsTwo += scores [counter][inner];
            }else if(counter ==2){
                totalsThree += scores [counter][inner];
            }else if(counter ==3){
                totalsFour += scores [counter][inner];
            }
        }
    }
}

private static String getResults(int currentEnd) {
    //format current results 
    String result = "";
    for (int count = 0; count < player.length; count++) {
        result += player[count];

        for (int i = 0; i <= currentEnd; i++) {
            result += "\t" + scores[count][i];
        }

        result += "\n";

    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output in a table format in Java's System.out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745206/output-in-a-table-format-in-javas-system-out)

Comment: no, no its not.

Comment: Can you tell us what's different about your question?

Comment: I am not using System.out.format... and I am not getting data from a database.

Comment: Source of the data is largely irrelevant (you don't need a database to use `System.out.format`). What are you using for output?

Comment: Did you even read the code? The output is happening in getResults()

Comment: Instead of using `System.out.println` you can use `System.out.format`. Seriously, give it a try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745206/output-in-a-table-format-in-javas-system-out#2745239

Comment: where am I suppose to put it? I tried in the getResults() and I did not work as well as my addScores method and it did not work as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see where the problem is. Inside `addScores()` method, you need to create 4 new `int` instances where you can save the score of each 4 players like this:

```
private static String getResults(int currentEnd) {      
    int player1totalscore = 0; //4 instances of int where each player's score will be stored.
    int player2totalscore = 0;
    int player3totalscore = 0;
    int player4totalscore = 0;

    for (int count = 0; count < player.length; count++) {           
        for (int i = 0; i <= currentEnd; i++) {
            if(count == 0) //when first player
                player1totalscore += scores[count][i];  //add score
            if(count == 1) //when 2nd player
                player2totalscore += scores[count][i];  //add score
            if(count == 2) //when 3rd player
                player3totalscore += scores[count][i];  //add score
            if(count == 3) //when 4th player
                player4totalscore += scores[count][i];  //add score            
        }           
    }
    String result = "";
    for (int count = 0; count < player.length; count++) {
        result += player[count];
        for (int i = 0; i <= currentEnd; i++) {             
            if(i==currentEnd){   //when the string is at player's last score entry, add his/her score at the end            
            if(count == 0)
                result += "\t" + scores[count][i] + "\t" + " | " + player1totalscore;
            if(count == 1)
                result += "\t" + scores[count][i] + "\t" + " | " + player2totalscore;
            if(count == 2)
                result += "\t" + scores[count][i] + "\t" + " | " + player3totalscore;   
            if(count == 3)
                result += "\t" + scores[count][i] + "\t" + " | " + player4totalscore;
            } else { //otherwise, keep adding individual scores
                result += "\t" + scores[count][i];
            }               
        }            
        result += "\n";            
    }
    return result;
}
```