# How to align the object output from a text file in java?

Tags: java

I've created an object called tour which is supposed to display an arraylist. Currently, the output is being displayed like this

[image]

This is a part of what I wrote in the file that it is supposed to read from:

> Bukit Broga;Selangor;0.00;1980;Nature;20000
>
> KKB Water Rafting;Selangor;80.0;1982;Outdoor Adventure;1000
>
> Pisang River;Selangor;0.00;1972;Nature;4000
>
> A-Famosa;Melaka;0.00;1511;Historical;20000
>
> Stadhyus Church;Melaka;0.00;1782;Historical;20000
>
> BabaNyonya Museum;Melaka;5.00;1970;Museum;20000
>
> Taming Sari;Melaka;0.00;1965;Historical;25000

```
else if (menu == 4)//display all object
{
    find = false;
    System.out.println("This is theTourism List taken from a file listed in tourismList arraylist");


    for (int i = 0; i < tourismList.size(); i++) {
        tour = tourismList.get(i);//retrieve object from list

        System.out.println(tour);//print object using toString

    }
}
```

Comment: Trying using `.printf(...)` instead of `println(..)` and set the spacing for the output as desired - see this quick reference for options https://www.baeldung.com/java-printstream-printf

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745206 help you?