# Processing not showing data values and not reading cities?

Tags: java, processing

Hello im having trouble with processing where its not outputting the data of my columns? It's reading the rows but inside each row it outputs it as a 0 except for "Number" even though there is data inside them?

Also i dont know how to seperate the cities as it definitly is not a int value?

My code:

```
int[][] data;

void setup() {

size(800, 600);

String[] lines = loadStrings("datasheet.csv");
println("there are " + lines.length + " lines");   

String[] header = split(lines[0], ','); 
println(header[0] + " " + header[1] + " " + header[2] + " " + header[3] + " " + header[4]);


data = new int[5][lines.length-1]; 

for (int i = 1 ; i < lines.length; i++) {
String[] dataStr = split(lines[i], ',');

data[0][i-1] = int (dataStr[0]);
data[1][i-1] = int (dataStr[1]);
data[2][i-1] = int (dataStr[2]);
data[3][i-1] = int (dataStr[3]);
data[4][i-1] = int (dataStr[4]);

println (data[0][i-1] + "  " + data[1][i-1] + "  " + data [2][i-1] + "  " + data [3][i-1] + "  " + 
data 
[4][i-1]);

}
}
```

[image: This is what it is outputting]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues in your code which you need to address:

**A.** Instead of printing the header in the following way:

```
println(header[0] + " " + header[1] + " " + header[2] + " " + header[3] + " " + header[4]);
```

you could do it in the following elegant way:

```
println(String.join(" ", header));
```

**B.** You need to declare `data` as `new int[no-of-rows][no-of-columns]` but you have done it the other way round. Moreover, instead of using a hardcoded value like `5`, you should have used `header.length`.

**C.** Printing the `data` can also be done elegantly using `String::join` in the same way as done above for printing the `header`.

Given below is the code incorporating these points:

```
String[][] data;

void setup() {
    size(800, 600);
    String[] lines = loadStrings("datasheet.csv");
    println("there are " + lines.length + " lines");
    String[] header = split(lines[0], ','); 
    println(String.join(" ", header));
    data = new String[lines.length -1][header.length];
    for (int i = 1 ; i < lines.length; i++) {
        String[] dataStr = split(lines[i], ',');
        data[i-1] = dataStr;
        println(String.join(" ", dataStr));
    }
}
```

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Hello Arvind. I tested your code but i get an error `cannot convert from String[] to int[]
` for `data[i] = dataStr;`

Comment: Fixed it. I hope, it works now. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: It seems to be working almost, but it doesn't read my 5th line which is my final line. It gives an error saying `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5` Also what is the best way to align them with their header names as the columns seem to be unorganised.

Comment: Fixed again. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Hello Arvind, if i wanted to put the data inside a table so it looks more organised how will i do this?

Comment: Do you mean displaying with table borders as spreadsheet does?

Comment: Yes that could also work but it would need to show it on the console itself and not on the window when the code is run.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745206/output-in-a-table-format-in-javas-system-out ? Feel free to comment in case you need any further support.