# How to Align a 2D array

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public void printTile () {
    for (int x = 0; x < tile.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < tile[x].length; y++) {
            tile[x][y].toString();
            System.out.print(tile[x][y].shapeString + "\t\t\t\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This method prints out the tile array however when I print it out it does not line up properly as the output appears to be like this:

```
SQ s: 4.0 c: red                EMPTY               EMPTY               EMPTY               EMPTY               
EMPTY               EMPTY               EMPTY               EMPTY               EMPTY               
EMPTY               EMPTY               EMPTY               EMPTY               EMPTY               
EMPTY               EMPTY               EMPTY               EMPTY               EMPTY               
EMPTY               EMPTY               EMPTY               EMPTY               EMPTY
```

Is there any way, where I can format and line up all the tiles properly ?

Comment: Well how would you do it 'by hand'?  If a tile is not EMPTY, then it shouldn't have that many tabs. Sounds like an `if` statement. Or you could use `String.format()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745206/output-in-a-table-format-in-javas-system-out/2745239#2745239