# I want to format two arraylist in form of table and save it in file using java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, arraylist, automated-tests

Hello every one I am creating test suite wer it verifies values generated in pdf document by extracting and comparing them with values generated in web-table.Now my approach to it is extract table header and table data and format them in their original table format i.e headers being headers and values placed in under correct header and save it in text file

for ref: This is from actual page and format I want
[image]

[image: This the scrolled same table]

Code:
Driver Code:

```
package Onsight.FrameWork;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import com.github.javafaker.Faker;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import onsight2.Pageobject.HomePage;
import onsight2.Pageobject.LoginPage;
import onsight2.Pageobject.ViewRport;

public class Webtable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<String> listoftable_row=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> table_header=new ArrayList<String>();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String urlString = "https://oinsightsvm1.westindia.cloudapp.azure.com:444/ctsOInsightsBMS/res/createReport.html";
        String userEmailString = "User66";
        String userPassword = "Avdhut@5201";
        String titleString;
        String textString="random";
        int pages;
        Faker faker = new Faker();
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        // options.addArguments("--ignore-ssl- errors=yes");
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get(urlString);
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        loginPage.login_username(userEmailString);
        loginPage.click0nsubmit();
        loginPage.EnterPassword(userPassword);
        loginPage.click0nsubmit();
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        homePage.view_report_values(textString);
        ViewRport viewRport=new ViewRport(driver);
        viewRport.view_data();
        table_header=viewRport.get_headers();
        pages=viewRport.no_of_pages();
        listoftable_row=viewRport.view_values(pages);
        for (int i = 0; i < table_header.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(table_header.get(i)+" "+"\t");
        }
        for (String table_row:listoftable_row) {
            System.out.println(table_row+" "+ "\t");
        }
        
        
//      
        
        
//      

        
    }

}
```

Page Object file:

```
package onsight2.Pageobject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import onsight2.Commonutilities.BaseComponenets;

public class ViewRport extends BaseComponenets {
    WebDriver driver;
    By view_dataBy = By.xpath("//button[contains(@title,'View data')]");
    By dataBy = By.xpath("//table[@id='reportDataTable-0']/tbody/tr ");
    By teable_headingBy = By.xpath(".//div[@class='dataTables_scrollHead']//tr[@id='report-data-table-header-0']/th");
    By data_baseTableBy=By.xpath("//table[@id='reportDataTable-0']");
    By dataTable_row=By.xpath("//table[@id='reportDataTable-0']/tbody/tr");
    By next_paginateBy = By.xpath("//li[@id='reportDataTable-0_next']");
    By next_pageBy = By.xpath("//div[@id='reportDataTable-0_paginate']/ul[@class='pagination']/li[@class='paginate_button page-item active']/following-sibling::li[1]");
    By current_pageBy=By.xpath( "//div[@id='reportDataTable-0_paginate']/ul[@class='pagination']/li[@class='paginate_button page-item active']");
    List<String> listoftable_row=new ArrayList<String>();  
    public ViewRport(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public List<String> get_headers() {
        IsVisible(teable_headingBy);
        List<WebElement> table_headerElement = driver.findElements(teable_headingBy);
        List<String> table_header=new ArrayList<String>();
        JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
//      System.out.println("Total no. of headers: " + table_headerElement.size());
        
        System.out.println("Headers: ");
        System.err.println("========");
        for (WebElement header : table_headerElement) {
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", header);
            table_header.add(header.getText());
        }
            return table_header;

    }
    
    public void view_data() {
        IsClickable(view_dataBy);
        WebElement view_data=driver.findElement(view_dataBy);
        view_data.click();
    }

    public List<String> view_values(int no_of_pages ) throws InterruptedException {
        
        int page_counter;
        String list;
        boolean flag=true;
        while (flag) {
            page_counter=Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(current_pageBy).getText());
            if (page_counter==no_of_pages) {
                listoftable_row.addAll(test());
                break;
            } else {
                listoftable_row.addAll(test());
                IsClickable(next_pageBy);
                driver.findElement(next_pageBy).click();
//              System.out.println("in pagination"+page_counter);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        }
        // page_counter=Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(current_pageBy).getText());
//      for (int i = 1; i <= no_of_pages    ; i++) {
//          listoftable_row.addAll(test());
//          IsClickable(next_pageBy);
//          
//          driver.findElement(next_pageBy).click();
//          System.out.println("in pagination"+i);
////            listoftable_row.add(list);
//          
////            test();
////            listoftable_row.add(list);
////            System.out.println(list);
//          Thread.sleep(5000);
//  
//      }
            
//          for (int i = 0; i < listoftable_row.size(); i++) {
//              System.out.println(listoftable_row.get(i));
//          }
return listoftable_row;
    }

    public int no_of_pages() {
        IsClickable(next_paginateBy);
        WebElement nextBtn = driver.findElement(next_paginateBy);
        if (!nextBtn.getAttribute("class").contains("disabled")) {
        int maxNum = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='reportDataTable-0_next']/preceding-sibling::li[1]")).getText());
        return maxNum;
        }
            return 1;}
public List<String> test() {
    List<String> listoftable_row2=new ArrayList<String>();
    String statuString;
    IsVisible(data_baseTableBy);
    WebElement dataTablebasElement=driver.findElement(data_baseTableBy);
    List<WebElement> dataTable_roWebElement=driver.findElements(dataTable_row);
    for (int i=0;i<dataTable_roWebElement.size();i++) {
//  System.out.println(dataTable_roWebElement.get(i).getText());
    listoftable_row2.add(dataTable_roWebElement.get(i).getText());
    
    }
//  System.out.println(listoftable_row2);
//  return listoftable_row2;
    return listoftable_row2;
   
    
}
    


}
```

Console O/P:

Table Header:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 108.0.5359.71 (1e0e3868ee06e91ad636a874420e3ca3ae3756ac-refs/branch-heads/5359@{#1016}) on port 28832
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Dec 21, 2022 7:48:02 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 108, so returning the closest version found: 107
Headers: 
========
TIMESTAMP   
SOURCE NAME     
SOURCE STATE    
ACK STATE   
MESSAGE TEXT    
LAST NOTES  
ALL NOTES   
ALARM VALUE     
LOW LIMIT
```

Table Body:

> 

```
09-12-22 06:07:42 Bldg4_Flr3_AHU_4_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg4_Flr3_AHU_4_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22 06:07:42
> Bldg4_Flr3_AHU_4_FilterSts Normal Unacked Bldg4_Flr3_AHU_4_FilterSts
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 06:07:42 Bldg3_Flr3_AHU_4_Trip
> Normal Unacked Bldg3_Flr3_AHU_4_Trip has normalised - - true -    
> 09-12-22 06:07:42 Bldg3_Flr3_AHU_4_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg3_Flr3_AHU_4_FilterSts has normalised - - true -   09-12-22
> 06:08:41 Bldg1_Flr1_FAS Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FAS has normalised -
> - true -   09-12-22 06:09:58 Bldg1_Chiller1_InTemp Normal Unacked - - 10.10 -      09-12-22 06:10:14 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 06:11:32
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip has normalised
> - - true -     09-12-22 06:13:46 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 06:13:46
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 06:15:15 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22
> 06:17:51 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_FilterSts has normalised - - true -   09-12-22
> 06:19:19 Bldg1_Flr1_CRAC_1_SpaceT Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_CRAC_1_SpaceT has normalised - - 28.83 19.0 °C      09-12-22
> 06:19:19 Bldg1_Flr1_CRAC_1_SpaceRh Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_CRAC_1_SpaceRh has normalised - - 55.63 40.0 %RH    09-12-22
> 06:19:31 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT has normalised - - 26.00 19.0 °C   09-12-22
> 06:20:16 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 06:21:33 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip
> Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip has normalised - - true -  
> 09-12-22 06:21:48 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has normalised - - true -     09-12-22 06:21:48
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 06:23:43 Bldg1_Flr1_FAS Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FAS has normalised - - true -   09-12-22 06:25:17
> Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 06:29:13 Bldg1_Flr1_CRAC_2_FilterSts
> Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_CRAC_2_FilterSts has normalised - - true -  
> 09-12-22 06:29:13 Bldg1_Flr1_CRAC_1_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_CRAC_1_FilterSts has normalised - - true -      09-12-22
> 06:29:13 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_FilterSts has normalised - - true -   09-12-22
> 06:29:13 Bldg1_Flr2_CRAC_3_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr2_CRAC_3_FilterSts has normalised - - true -      09-12-22
> 06:29:13 Bldg1_Flr2_CRAC_4_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr2_CRAC_4_FilterSts has normalised - - true -      09-12-22
> 06:29:50 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 06:29:50 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts
> Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has normalised - - true -     
> 09-12-22 06:30:18 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22 06:31:34
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip has normalised
> - - true -     09-12-22 06:33:58 Bldg1_Chiller1_InTemp Normal Unacked - - 10.19 -      09-12-22 06:35:16 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT has normalised - - 26.00 19.0 °C   09-12-22
> 06:35:19 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 06:37:51 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts
> Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has normalised - - true -     
> 09-12-22 06:37:51 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22 06:38:44
> Bldg1_Flr1_FAS Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FAS has normalised - - true -
>    09-12-22 06:40:20 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22 06:41:35
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip has normalised
> - - true -     09-12-22 06:45:21 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 06:45:29
> Bldg1_Chiller1_InTemp Normal Unacked - - 10.12 -   09-12-22 06:45:53
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 06:45:53 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22
> 06:49:28 Bldg1_Chiller1_InTemp Normal Unacked - - 10.09 -      09-12-22
> 06:50:23 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 06:51:36 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip
> Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip has normalised - - true -  
> 09-12-22 06:53:45 Bldg1_Flr1_FAS Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FAS has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 06:53:54 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22
> 06:53:54 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has normalised - - true -     09-12-22 06:55:24
> Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 06:56:16 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT
> Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT has normalised - - 26.00 19.0
> °C     09-12-22 06:59:05 Flr1_Area1_SD6_Alm Normal Unacked - - true -     
> 09-12-22 06:59:05 Flr1_Area1_SD5_Alm Normal Unacked - - true -    
> 09-12-22 06:59:05 Flr1_Area1_SD4_Alm Normal Unacked - - true -    
> 09-12-22 07:00:00 Bldg1_Flr6_AHU32_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - -
> true -     09-12-22 07:00:26 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22 07:00:36
> VAV1_DamperStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:00:41
> Bldg1_Flr3_AHU1_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -      09-12-22
> 07:00:41 Bldg1_Flr3_AHU2_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -    
> 09-12-22 07:00:43 VAV1_DamperStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -     
> 09-12-22 07:00:44 VAV2_DamperStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -     
> 09-12-22 07:00:47 Bldg1_Flr4_AHU11_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - -
> true -     09-12-22 07:00:48 Bldg1_Flr4_AHU12_ValveStuckAlert Normal
> Unacked - - true -     09-12-22 07:00:49 VAV1_DamperStuckAlert Normal
> Unacked - - true -     09-12-22 07:00:50 VAV2_DamperStuckAlert Normal
> Unacked - - true -     09-12-22 07:00:53
> Bldg1_Flr5_AHU21_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -     09-12-22
> 07:00:54 Bldg1_Flr5_AHU22_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -   
> 09-12-22 07:00:56 VAV1_DamperStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -     
> 09-12-22 07:00:56 VAV2_DamperStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -     
> 09-12-22 07:00:59 Bldg1_Flr6_AHU31_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - -
> true -     09-12-22 07:01:37 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:01:56
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:01:56 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22
> 07:04:28 Bldg1_Chiller1_InTemp Normal Unacked - - 10.10 -      09-12-22
> 07:05:27 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:07:20 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_SpaceT
> Offnormal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_SpaceT has crossed low limit - -
> 18.33 19.0 °C      09-12-22 07:08:18 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_RaRh Offnormal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_RaRh has crossed low limit - - 39.22 40.0 %RH
>    09-12-22 07:08:19 Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_2_SpaceRh Offnormal Unacked
> Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_2_SpaceRh has crossed low limit - - 39.06 40.0 %RH     
> 09-12-22 07:08:48 Bldg1_Flr1_FAS Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FAS has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:08:58 Bldg1_Chiller1_InTemp Normal
> Unacked - - 10.28 -    09-12-22 07:09:03 Flr1_Area1_SD2_Alm Normal
> Unacked - - true -     09-12-22 07:09:03 Flr1_Area1_SD3_Alm Normal
> Unacked - - true -     09-12-22 07:09:57 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has normalised - - true -     09-12-22
> 07:09:57 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:10:29 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip
> Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has normalised - - true -    
> 09-12-22 07:10:58 Cond_DeltaT Normal Unacked - - 5.70 -    09-12-22
> 07:10:58 KW_Ton_CH1 Normal Unacked - - 1.70 -      09-12-22 07:11:21
> Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_1_SpaceDP Normal Unacked Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_1_SpaceDP has
> normalised - - 40.00 50.0 Pa   09-12-22 07:11:21
> Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_1_SpaceT Normal Unacked Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_1_SpaceT has
> normalised - - 17.00 19.0 °C   09-12-22 07:11:38 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip
> Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip has normalised - - true -  
> 09-12-22 07:12:01 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT has normalised - - 26.00 19.0 °C   09-12-22
> 07:13:58 Bldg1_Chiller1_InTemp Normal Unacked - - 10.22 -      09-12-22
> 07:15:30 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:17:58 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts
> Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has normalised - - true -     
> 09-12-22 07:17:58 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22 07:20:31
> Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:21:39 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip has normalised - - true -      09-12-22
> 07:23:49 Bldg1_Flr1_FAS Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FAS has normalised -
> - true -   09-12-22 07:25:33 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:25:59
> Bldg1_Chiller1_InTemp Normal Unacked - - 10.34 -   09-12-22 07:25:59
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:25:59 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22
> 07:27:46 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT has normalised - - 26.00 19.0 °C   09-12-22
> 07:30:34 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:31:41 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip
> Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip has normalised - - true -  
> 09-12-22 07:34:01 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has normalised - - true -     09-12-22 07:34:01
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:35:35 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22
> 07:36:36 VAV1_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -   09-12-22 07:36:37
> VAV2_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:36:38
> VAV3_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:36:39
> VAV4_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:36:44
> VAV1_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:36:44
> VAV1_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:36:45
> VAV1_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:36:46
> VAV1_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:36:50
> VAV1_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:36:51
> VAV1_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:36:51
> VAV1_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:36:52
> VAV1_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:36:56
> VAV1_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:36:57
> VAV1_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:36:57
> VAV1_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:36:58
> VAV1_Starving Normal Unacked - - true -    09-12-22 07:37:21
> Bldg1_Flr2_CRAC_3_SpaceDP Offnormal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_CRAC_3_SpaceDP
> has crossed low limit - - 41.65 50.0 Pa    09-12-22 07:37:21
> Bldg1_Flr2_CRAC_3_SpaceT Offnormal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_CRAC_3_SpaceT
> has crossed low limit - - 17.13 19.0 °C    09-12-22 07:38:50
> Bldg1_Flr1_FAS Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FAS has normalised - - true -
>    09-12-22 07:39:14 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_FilterSts has normalised - - true -   09-12-22
> 07:39:14 Bldg1_Flr2_CRAC_4_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr2_CRAC_4_FilterSts has normalised - - true -      09-12-22
> 07:39:14 Bldg1_Flr1_CRAC_2_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_CRAC_2_FilterSts has normalised - - true -      09-12-22
> 07:39:14 Bldg1_Flr1_CRAC_1_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_CRAC_1_FilterSts has normalised - - true -      09-12-22
> 07:39:14 Bldg1_Flr2_CRAC_3_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr2_CRAC_3_FilterSts has normalised - - true -      09-12-22
> 07:40:36 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:41:43 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip
> Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip has normalised - - true -  
> 09-12-22 07:42:02 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22 07:42:02
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:45:38 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22
> 07:46:29 Bldg1_Chiller1_InTemp Normal Unacked - - 10.07 -      09-12-22
> 07:48:46 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT has normalised - - 26.00 19.0 °C   09-12-22
> 07:50:04 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has normalised - - true -     09-12-22 07:50:04
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:50:39 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22
> 07:51:44 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:53:52 Bldg1_Flr1_FAS Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FAS has normalised - - true -   09-12-22 07:55:40
> Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:56:58 Bldg4_Flr3_AHU_4_SpaceT
> Offnormal Unacked Bldg4_Flr3_AHU_4_SpaceT has crossed hi limit - -
> 25.46 19.0 °C      09-12-22 07:58:05 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 07:58:05
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:00:00
> Bldg1_Flr6_AHU32_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -     09-12-22
> 08:00:00 Bldg1_Flr6_AHU33_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -   
> 09-12-22 08:00:01 Bldg1_Flr6_AHU34_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - -
> true -     09-12-22 08:00:36 VAV1_DamperStuckAlert Normal Unacked - -
> true -     09-12-22 08:00:41 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22 08:00:41
> Bldg1_Flr3_AHU1_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -      09-12-22
> 08:00:41 Bldg1_Flr3_AHU2_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -    
> 09-12-22 08:00:43 VAV1_DamperStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -     
> 09-12-22 08:00:44 VAV2_DamperStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -     
> 09-12-22 08:00:47 Bldg1_Flr4_AHU11_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - -
> true -     09-12-22 08:00:48 Bldg1_Flr4_AHU12_ValveStuckAlert Normal
> Unacked - - true -     09-12-22 08:00:50 VAV1_DamperStuckAlert Normal
> Unacked - - true -     09-12-22 08:00:50 VAV2_DamperStuckAlert Normal
> Unacked - - true -     09-12-22 08:00:53
> Bldg1_Flr5_AHU21_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -     09-12-22
> 08:00:54 Bldg1_Flr5_AHU22_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -   
> 09-12-22 08:00:56 VAV1_DamperStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -     
> 09-12-22 08:00:56 VAV2_DamperStuckAlert Normal Unacked - - true -     
> 09-12-22 08:00:59 Bldg1_Flr6_AHU31_ValveStuckAlert Normal Unacked - -
> true -     09-12-22 08:01:45 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:04:32
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT has
> normalised - - 26.00 19.0 °C   09-12-22 08:05:43 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip
> Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has normalised - - true -    
> 09-12-22 08:06:07 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22 08:06:07
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:07:52 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_FilterSts
> Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_FilterSts has normalised - - true -   
> 09-12-22 08:08:53 Bldg1_Flr1_FAS Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FAS has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:10:44 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22
> 08:11:46 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:14:08 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22
> 08:14:08 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has normalised - - true -     09-12-22 08:15:45
> Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:15:59 KW_Ton_CH1 Normal Unacked -
> - 1.70 -   09-12-22 08:15:59 Cond_DeltaT Normal Unacked - - 5.70 -     09-12-22 08:17:41 Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_1_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_1_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22 08:17:41
> Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_1_FilterSts Normal Unacked Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_1_FilterSts
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:17:41 Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_4_Trip
> Normal Unacked Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_4_Trip has normalised - - true -    
> 09-12-22 08:17:41 Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_2_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_2_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22 08:17:41
> Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_3_Trip has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:17:41 Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_4_FilterSts
> Normal Unacked Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_4_FilterSts has normalised - - true -   
> 09-12-22 08:17:41 Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_3_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_3_FilterSts has normalised - - true -   09-12-22
> 08:17:41 Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_5_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_5_Trip
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:17:41
> Bldg2_Flr3_AHU_4_FilterSts Normal Unacked Bldg2_Flr3_AHU_4_FilterSts
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:17:41
> Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_2_FilterSts Normal Unacked Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_2_FilterSts
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:17:41
> Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_5_FilterSts Normal Unacked Bldg2_Flr3_VAV_5_FilterSts
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:17:41 Bldg2_Flr3_AHU_4_Trip
> Normal Unacked Bldg2_Flr3_AHU_4_Trip has normalised - - true -    
> 09-12-22 08:17:43 Bldg3_Flr3_AHU_4_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg3_Flr3_AHU_4_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22 08:17:43
> Bldg4_Flr3_AHU_4_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg4_Flr3_AHU_4_Trip has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:17:43 Bldg3_Flr3_AHU_4_FilterSts
> Normal Unacked Bldg3_Flr3_AHU_4_FilterSts has normalised - - true -   
> 09-12-22 08:17:43 Bldg4_Flr3_AHU_4_FilterSts Normal Unacked
> Bldg4_Flr3_AHU_4_FilterSts has normalised - - true -   09-12-22
> 08:19:30 Flr1_Area1_SD5_Alm Normal Unacked - - true -      09-12-22
> 08:19:30 Flr1_Area1_SD4_Alm Normal Unacked - - true -      09-12-22
> 08:19:30 Flr1_Area1_SD6_Alm Normal Unacked - - true -      09-12-22
> 08:20:17 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_1_SpaceT has normalised - - 26.00 19.0 °C   09-12-22
> 08:20:47 Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr2_AHU_3_Trip
> has normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:20:58 Bldg1_Chiller1_InTemp
> Normal Unacked - - 10.28 -     09-12-22 08:21:47 Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip
> Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_Trip has normalised - - true -  
> 09-12-22 08:22:09 Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip Normal Unacked
> Bldg1_Flr1_AHU_2_Trip has normalised - - true -    09-12-22 08:22:09
> Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts Normal Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FCU_FilterSts has
> normalised - - true -      09-12-22 08:23:54 Bldg1_Flr1_FAS Normal
> Unacked Bldg1_Flr1_FAS has normalised - - true -   09-12-22 08:24:04
> Flr1_Area1_SD2_Alm Normal Unacked - - true -
```

Comment: And what is it that you are asking? What is the problem that you have encountered?

Comment: @ThomasTimbul. I want to format both the array list  in properly, as the extracted output is from listofrows is very crude. I want to format it in a way tabular format, where values of table_header be the table headers for each column respectively and the values of table rows under each respective cell , just like a table.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul, or in other words I want to imitate the table in image, in textual form

Comment: @ThomasTimbul If you want to skip the table header part no issues. I just want a way to    properly refined and format the contents  of tablerow arraylist

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745206/output-in-a-table-format-in-javas-system-out